# Usar SWRevealViewController con TabBarController Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Buenas tardes, estoy usando esta librería para poder abrir un side menu:

> https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController.git

Me funciona todo correctamente, abre y cierra el menú correctamente, también estoy usando un TabBar, me está quedando así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí todo bien, mi consulta viene cuando por ejemplo selecciono una opción de la tabla ("fotos clasicas", "lozas", "lápidas"..), lo que pasa cuando selecciono uno de esas opciones es que me abre una vista completamente nueva eliminando todo lo demás, elimina las vistas del tabBar y todo.

Esta imagen es de mis vistas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, especificamente mi consulta sería; **¿Cómo hago para al dar clic a una opción de la tabla ("fotos clasicas", "lozas", "lápidas"..) solo reemplace la vista sin eliminar las opciones del tabBar ni nada?.**

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas que se abra una vista nueva sin que desaparezca el tabBar tienes que abrirla como push desde una vista propia del tabBar.

Estás intentando mezclar dos tipos de menús que funcionan de forma diferente.

La idea del menú lateral es tener una vista distinta para cada una de las opciones del menú, y cada una de ellas con el menú integrado, haciendo que parezca que el menú es un elemento estático.

El tabBar, que es nativo de iOS, mantiene todas sus vistas, de manera que no tiene que volver a cargarlas al cambiar entre ellas.

Es posible que una vez abierta una opción del menú lateral puedas volver al tabBar con `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` si se abren como modal y con `self.navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)` si se abren como push (este no siempre es necesario si aparece automáticamente en la navegación)